# ubuntu on mac-mini: shell script to fix my screen-resolution?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu installed in two machines: a laptop and a Mac Mini. While in the Laptop the screen is fine, on Mac Mini the resolutions option showing are only two and neither match perfectly well. Currently it shows the option: 1024x768 or 800x600.

It is a LED monitor Philips 24" (61cm) model 244EL2. I have never got such similar problem when running Ubuntu on PC. Is it a problem of drivers, related with Apple Mac Mini?

I wonder if some bash script could get this thing fixed? Or if someone could suggest a recipe on this?

Comment: Have you tried `xrandr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got with a similar problem some time ago. The only thing that got it fixed for me was to replace the grub with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/linux.html). Basically, after having started your Ubuntu, download the [rEFInd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) for linux, and install it. Then reboot and when you login again, the screen resolution should got automatically fixed to the optimal possible match for your monitor.